# While statements example in "Java, a Beginner's Guide"

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int e;
        int result;

        for(int i =0; i <10; i++){
            result = 1;
            e = i;

            while(e > 0){
                result *= 2;
                e--;

            }

            System.out.println("2 to the " + i + " power is " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

I am going through Java, A Beginner's Guide, by Herbert Schildt.  I am unclear on the above code.  When i is set to zero on the first iteration, the while statement is skipped because e will be set to zero and the while condition will not be true.  Thus i will be 1 and result will be 1 and this answer will be printed out.

In the second iteration, i and e will be 1, thus the while statement will be executed because e > 1 and the result will therefore be 2.  So far, so good.  However, e is decremented by 1 after the result is calculated so now e is back to 0.

The third iteration where i is set to 2 is where I am getting lost.  Since e is now zero again, what happens on this iteration?  Doesn't the program get kicked out of the while loop and go back to the beginning again since the while condition is no longer true?  If so, doesn't result get set back to 1, which will have result being equal to 2 again instead of 4 after the while loop for i = 2 is run?

I understand the program in all subsequent iterations of i since e will not be set back to zero again after it gets past this third iteration.  But I'm confused as to why the cumulative result isn't lost as a consequence of decrementing e back to zero after the second iteration.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Since e is now zero again` - that's not true. e is assigned the current value of i in each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Why do you think that assignment `e = i;` bothers what `e` had previously?

Comment: I have no idea why people downvote your question. You provided a code and described in details what is your problem. You did well.

Comment: I get it now.  My problem is that: 1) I didn't fully understand how the while-loop within a for-loop worked and, 2) I assumed that the expression result *= 2 was going to use the result from the prior iteration of the for-loop to build upon the the next iterations answer rather than start from scratch and start the 2*2*2... multiplication chain over from scratch.  I should have focused on the while-loop and realized that the while-loop would iterate many more times than would the for-loop and that the results of the previous for-loop would be ignored after i was incremented.  Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way to figure out how these variables are interchanged between the loop is to note them out on the pad along with their relevant output after an iteration, doing so would help you figure out with ease what is happening. I find that noting things down is very important to understand complex loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` cycle is inside the `for` cycle. Let's study the `while` cycle first. It will multiply `result` with 2 and decrement `e` while `e` is bigger than `0`, essentially, the result will be

**initial value * 2^i**

now, the for cycle goes from `0` to `10` and in each iteration initializes `result` with `1` and `e` with `i` (the *power*). It will calculate **2^i** in each iteration except the very first, where `i` is `0` and therefore `e>0` will be `false`. And the iteration will `println` the `result` in the end.

> When i is set to zero on the first iteration, the while statement is
>   skipped because e will be set to zero and the while condition will not
>   be true.

That's correct.

> In the second iteration, i and e will be 1, thus the while statement
>   will be executed because e > 1 and the result will therefore be 2. So
>   far, so good. However, e is decremented by 1 after the result is
>   calculated so now e is back to 0.

That's correct (if you meant `e > 0` there).

> The third iteration where i is set to 2 is where I am getting lost.
>   Since e is now zero again, what happens on this iteration? Doesn't the
>   program get kicked out of the while loop and go back to the beginning
>   again since the while condition is no longer true? If so, doesn't
>   result get set back to 1, which will have result being equal to 2
>   again instead of 4 after the while loop for i = 2 is run?

Incorrect. `e` is `0` indeed, but only until the line of

```
e = i;
```

where the value of `i`, which is 2 will be assigned to `e`. So `e` will be `2` at the start of the `while` loop and the `while` condition will be `true` twice, therefore you will have two iterations for the `while` loop.

> I understand the program in all subsequent iterations of i since e
>   will not be set back to zero again after it gets past this third
>   iteration. But I'm confused as to why the cumulative result isn't lost
>   as a consequence of decrementing e back to zero after the second
>   iteration.

Incorrect. `e` will be `0` at the end of each iteration of the `while` loop, but it will be `i` before each `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

> In the second iteration, i and e will be 1, thus the while statement
>   will be executed because e > 1 and the result will therefore be 2. So
>   far, so good. However, e is decremented by 1 after the result is
>   calculated so now e is back to 0.

Because `e > 0`, but apart from that, this is exactly right.

> The third iteration where i is set to 2 is where I am getting lost.
>   Since e is now zero again, what happens on this iteration?

```
    for(int i =0; i <10; i++){
        result = 1;
        e = i;

        while(e > 0){
            result *= 2;
            e--;

        }

        System.out.println("2 to the " + i + " power is " + result);
    }
```

You're correct in thinking that after the second iteration of the `for` loop, `e` will be `0`. But there's this beautiful line at the beginning: `e = i`;
In the third iteration, `i` will be `2`, which means after `e = i` (and right before the `while`), `e` will be set to `2`. Not `0`.